# Where are crontab -e settings saved in ubuntu 16.04? Working, but can't find

Tags: cron

I created a cron job by invoking:

```
# crontab -e
```

but I can't find the file with my edits.

Here's the /etc/crontab file:

```
# m h dom mon dow user  command

117 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly1

25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --repo$
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --repo$

52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --repo$
```

crontab -e shows

```
*/2 * * * * /home/avery/Dropbox/Scripts/lftp_download.sh
```

Anybody know which file my edits might be? I've looked at most the cron-related files in `/etc` but I can't find the one that's loaded when I type `crontab -e`.

Also, is there a log file in Ubuntu for cron?

Thanks in advance,
Avery

Answer (score 7):

Under `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/`.

You can find this by looking up the manpage for crontab by:

```
man crontab
```

Comment: Oh, OK!  I see that in the manpage now.  Thanks for the quick answer.  Hope this helps someone else. Also, must RTFM more often.